# Twitter OGP not working with Laravel & Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, twitter, share-open-graph

I don't think I miss anything in meta tags. I get the error message below when I try validating an URL I set here: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  4 metatags were found
ERROR: No card found (Card error)
```

The URL I want to show an OGP image for: http://apex-profile-generator.herokuapp.com/profile/4

Meta tags in my Laravel app.

```
@section('meta')
    <meta name="description" content="ApexProfiler 自分のプレイを可視化しよう" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="ApexProfiler" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{ $user->name }}さんのProfile | ApexProfiler" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::full() }}/{{ $user->id }}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://stats-graph.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bosyu/RpXKLmsIssc6yAP1eAUGOqhPYkIPwl8CHrWB8WIj.txt">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
    <meta property='twitter:title' content="{{ $user->name }}さんのProfile | ApexProfiler"/>
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::full() }}/{{ $user->id }}"/>
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://stats-graph.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bosyu/RpXKLmsIssc6yAP1eAUGOqhPYkIPwl8CHrWB8WIj.txt">
@endsection
```

Actual result in a browsed
[image]

It surely displays all the necessary tags, I believe. Does anyone have any idea why I still get the error?

Comment: I don't see any of those tags if I open that link page in a browser, or if I use curl to grab the page with the Twitter user-agent.

Comment: I cannot set an OGP image if only authenticated users are allowed to access the page...?

Comment: The url needs to be accessible without authentication.